# Is it allowed to calculate the derivative like that?

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions, derivatives

Let's say I'm supposed to calculate the derivative of $f(x)= \arccos(7x^{4}+3x^{2})$.

Is it allowed to do the following:

I know from our readings that $$(\arccos(x))'=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}$$

$\Rightarrow$

$$f'(x) = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(7x^{4}+3x^{2})}}\cdot (28x^{3}+6x)$$

I wouldn't know any other way of doing it anyway but I'm not sure if it would be allowed too. It seems to be correct at least.

What do you think, if we defined the derivation of arccosx in our readings already, is this allowed?

Comment: Yes, that's simply chain rule.  I don't quite see any problem with this (except you probably meant to make it $(7x^4+3x^2)^{\color{red}2}$)

Comment: Oh right thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The true definition of the derivative of arc tangent is as follows.

If y=arctan(u), (where u is a function of x ) then y'= -$\frac{u'}{\sqrt(1-u^2)}$

This is why your method worked.

Notice that since the derivative of x with respect to x is 1, that this formula works for arctan x as well. The formula in your book is actually a special case of this more general one.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you're allowed to do it. It would probably be even better if you mentioned the use of the chainrule as well.

Be aware though that

$f'(x)=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(7x^4+3x^2)^2}}\cdot(28x^3+6x)$